# Building app from the cordova cli fails

Tags: windows, cordova, ionic-framework, windows-phone

Here's what I have installed on my machine:

- cordova CLI: 6.5.0
- Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.17
- Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
- ios-deploy version: Not installed
- ios-sim version: Not installed
- OS: Windows 10
- Node Version: v6.11.0
- Xcode version: Not installed

I'm writing an app with ionic 1.3.3 angular 1.5.3 and cordova 6.5

When I run this command: 
**cordova build windows --appx=uap**

I get this error:

Processing settings for platform: windows
Building project:

```
C:\Users\aubrey\Source\Repos\SelfServiceApp\SelfServiceApp\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj
        Configuration : debug
        Platform      : anycpu
C:\Users\aubrey\Source\Repos\SelfServiceApp\SelfServiceApp\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj(61,5): error M
SB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio..Defau
lt.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk
.
Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe: Command failed with exit code 1
```

I'm not sure why it doesn't work. The android build works.

Comment: The file Microsoft.Default.Props is actually not there.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because the dependent plugin's source files are not set as "Content" type. Using cordova-windows version 5.0.0 might solve your error.